# How to get current event from fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcalendar

I'm making a web app that displays content scheduled on a calendar. Like TV listings for example. I'm using [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io) to provide the user interface.

Now I need to call the current event in fullcalendar. I'm surprised that I couldn't find any native method in the docs.

How do you manage to get the current event in a simple way?

Comment: Could you share, what you have done so far?

Comment: "current event". There may be many events on the calendar at any given moment. Which one are you defining as "current"? If you mean one which overlaps the current date and time, you can do it easily by calling the clientEvents method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) passing in a filter function which checks the start/end dates of each event to see whether the event overlaps the current date/time. If it does, return it, if not, don't. Note it could be possible for multiple events to be "current", assuming my definition of that matches yours.

Answer (score 0):

You may try followings:

```
var local = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01T12:00:00');
```